How to hide timestamps in react production after build in vite?
My phase of production is currenly at pentest, which I need to pass every test, even it's low. There's a pentest that says
**Timestamp Disclosure - Unix**
Description: A timestamp was disclosed by the application/web server. - Unix.
Evidence: 1540483477, which evaluates to: 2018-10-25 23:04:37.

I found out that in react production, there's a function that written like this
/** @license React v16.13.1
 * react-is.production.min.js
 *
 * Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */
 
 ...rest of code....
 
function V$e(e) {
    for (var t = 0, n, r = 0, i = e.length; i >= 4; ++r,
    i -= 4)
        n = e.charCodeAt(r) & 255 | (e.charCodeAt(++r) & 255) << 8 | (e.charCodeAt(++r) & 255) << 16 | (e.charCodeAt(++r) & 255) << 24,
        n = (n & 65535) * 1540483477 + ((n >>> 16) * 59797 << 16),
        n ^= n >>> 24,
        t = (n & 65535) * 1540483477 + ((n >>> 16) * 59797 << 16) ^ (t & 65535) * 1540483477 + ((t >>> 16) * 59797 << 16);
    switch (i) {
    case 3:
        t ^= (e.charCodeAt(r + 2) & 255) << 16;
    case 2:
        t ^= (e.charCodeAt(r + 1) & 255) << 8;
    case 1:
        t ^= e.charCodeAt(r) & 255,
        t = (t & 65535) * 1540483477 + ((t >>> 16) * 59797 << 16)
    }
    return t ^= t >>> 13,
    t = (t & 65535) * 1540483477 + ((t >>> 16) * 59797 << 16),
    ((t ^ t >>> 15) >>> 0).toString(36)
}

I'm assuming that it comes from react library itself. Because its being used everywhere. Is there anyway to hide this or maybe replace it? Thanks!
